# Adding Attribute in Text box using VB.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, onfocus

I Have a TextBox control in my ASP.NET Page

```
<asp:TextBox ID="PassTB" runat="server" CssClass="PasswordTB" />
```

And what I want is to add a new Attrribute named `OnFocus` 
I made that by adding this

```
PassTB.Attributes.Add("OnFocus", "<%PassMessage%>")
```

Line in `Page Load` sub
And the Attribute is Added but it is not working
I'am focusing on `TextBox` and the code do not even pass from the `Public sub`

```
Public Sub PassMessage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
```

The all Idea here is to raise a Panel with an appropriate message in order to assist a client in creation of a password.

Comment: "onfocus" expects to be given the name of a _JavaScript_ method...this is a client-side thing, you can't use it to trigger a random server-side method. If you want to run some server-side code at that moment, you have to make an AJAX call to a WebMethod. But what do you actually want your application to do when the user focuses on the text box? Perhaps it can be done in JavaScript easily.

Comment: @ADyson Yes I did that also and works fine for addition of the Attribute. But Also not work. Passes without working. Is it possible to assist me with a code sample?

Comment: " Yes I did that also"...did what exactly? I don't think you have understood my comment.

Comment: @ADyson What I did is that <script type="text/javascript">
        function PassMess(obj) {
            document.getElementById("PassTB").innerHTML = obj;
        }
        </script>

Comment: ok and what did you expect to happen when you did this? 1) your onfocus attribute doesn't actually execute your JS method. 2) Even if it did, it doesn't pass a parameter to the method, so `obj` would always be null, 3) `document.getElementById("PassTB")` may not find the right element because ASP.NET generates unique IDs for each container - unless you change the setting in your web.config. 4) textboxes don't have an `innerHTML` property. 5) It's unclear how any of this is relevant to your VB code.

Comment: Like I said, tell us what you're really trying to achieve and maybe we can help you. So far your actual code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @ADyson What to achieve is to  raise a Panel with an appropriate message in order to assist a client in creation of a password.

Comment: There's no reason for that to involve **any** server side VB code. Remember, your VB code **only** runs when you have a postback, and that means a full page refresh. Do that only when you have to, and use javascript the rest of the time.

Comment: `PassTB.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "PassMess()")` will add the attribute correctly in order to make the JS function run. After that you just need to have a hidden `<div>` somewhere appropriate in your page, and use the code to make it visible. And then have a way to hide it again if necessary. You can easily find examples of this kind of thing online using JavaScript and HTML.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn For that reason I need an assistant

Comment: @ADyson I Did that you instruct me and when I focus on the TextBox throw me a debugger error ` 'PassMessage' is undefined`

Comment: PassMess() not PassMessage() - you have to call the function with the same name you defined it!

Comment: @ADyson I've change it to this `"OnFocus", "PassMess(PassMessage())` And it returns me the same error 'PassMessage' is undefined' 
The script is running but something else happens

Comment: Yes because you don't have a function called PassMessage()...as I already mentioned. You told me you created one called PassMess() so that's what you have to use. I don't understand why you tried to put one inside the other? Especially one which doesn't exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183535/discussion-between-lefteris-gkinis-and-adyson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally with the assistant from @ADyson solved the puzzle. 
And it was so simple right from the start. Thats why I 'm giving it to all in order to have a solution on it.
First of all we add the following Attributes to the ASP.NET control `TextBox`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="PassTB" OnFocus="MessageIn()" runat="server" CssClass="PasswordTB"  MaxLength="20" />
```

The `OnFocus` attribute is not build-in to the control but it is not throwing any error as well if we add it like above.
In the `Message Panel` and exactly in the 'cssClass' we add the following

```
.PassInstrPanel {
visibility: hidden;
text-align: left;
margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
width: auto;
height: auto;
background-color: antiquewhite;}
```

Pay attention to `Visibility` which is `"hidden"`
That means the corresponding Panel it not saw in client site but it is alive in server site
Now since we made all these it's the time to add two functions in Java.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MessageOut() {
            var m = document.getElementById("page_main_PassInstructionPanel");
        m.style.visibility = "hiden";
    }
    function MessageIn() {
            var m = document.getElementById("page_main_PassInstructionPanel");
        m.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    </script>
```

When the Page is load it not any message will saw because it is `hidden`
By the time the `asp.net:TextBox`control is focused the `OnFocus` Attribute run the java function `MessageIn()` and the message appears
And finally by the time we push the button "I got it" we run the other Java function `MessageOut()`
And that is all.
I want to thanks @ADyson for his valuable assistant.